# How to plot the frequency response of butterworth filters using MATLAB

Tags: matlab, filter, frequency

I constructed a code to design 4 filters using butterworth IIR. Low,high,bandpass and bandstop.
Input Diolog window opens up to take in user inputs, I set the default values to :

```
def = {'5','200','40','50','3','30'}; for Low and High pass
AND
def = {'5','500','60', '200','50','250','3','30'}; for bandpass and bandstop
Order of Filter
Fsampling (Hz)
Fpass (Fpass 1 and 2) (Hz)
Fstop (Fstop 1 and 2) (Hz)
Ripple factors (dB)
Stop attenuation (dB)
```

for the time being.and using a for loop (1-->4) to calculate B and A components

```
   [n Fn] = buttord(Fpass,Fstop,Rp,Rs);
   [B,A] = butter(N,Fn,str);
   B_Comp{i} = B;
   A_Comp{i} = A;
```

Now..I need to plot their frequency responses for each filter, so  using

```
for i=1:4
   freqz(B_Comp(i),A_Comp(i));
   figure;
end
```

But this error comes up :

```
 ??? Function 'fft' is not defined for values of class 'cell'.
Error in ==> fft at 36
   [varargout{1:nargout}] = builtin('fft', varargin{:});

Error in ==> freqz at 94
    h = dividenowarn(fft(b,s.*nfft),fft(a,s.*nfft)).';

Error in ==> dsp1 at 62
    freqz(B_Comp(i),A_Comp(i));
```

How do i solve this problem.. any help is appreciated

Answer (score 3):

Don't use cells when you want to `fft`, try before to use `cell2mat`. For example:

```
 freqz(cell2mat(B_Comp(i)),cell2mat(A_Comp(i)));
```

Comment: can I just use : freqz(B_Comp{i},A_Comp{i}).. Notice the braces instead of brackets